# Magento2 How to setup cronjob to automatically start magento2 import?

Tags: magento2, import

There should be a possibility to setup a cron, which does the system -> import. I want to automatically start an import which I normally start from the magento2 admin GUI. The import is getting it's csv from local destination.

Does somebody know how I could do this?